# Tooltip for disabled button on hover in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a submit button in my form which is enabled if the form is valid, otherwise, it will be in disabled state. I want to add a popup message on hover over the disabled button not enabled button. How to add it dynamically according to enable and disable state in jQuery?

My code is in AngularJs, But I want to apply this tooltip using jQuery.

Html markup:

```
<button data-toggle="tooltip" title=" Please fill the mandatory fields..!" 
        type="submit" id="continue_button"
        class="submit"  
        ng-disabled="!form.$valid" ng-click="continueForm()">Submit</button>
```

JS part:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
```

In this case the tooltip works when the button is on enable. But I need the tooltip message should show only when the button is on disable.

Can anyone provide the solution in jQuery?

Comment: What tooltips do you use - jQuery UI? Bootstrap? Some other lib?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via CSS. The "pointer-events" property is what's preventing the tooltip from appearing. You can get disabled buttons to display tooltip by overriding the "pointer-events" property set by bootstrap.

```
#continue_button{
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Another solution is you can also wrap the disabled button and put the tooltip on the wrapper:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrapper" data-title="Dieser Link führt zu Google">
    <button class="btn btn-default" disabled>button disabled</button>
</div>
```

If the wrapper has `display:inline` then the tooltip doesn't seem to work. Using `display:block` and  `display:inline-block` seem to work fine. It also appears to work fine with a floated wrapper.

JSFiddle that works with the Bootstrap with adding `pointer-events: none;` for the disabled button.
[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cSSUA/209/)

UPDATE- if you want to display tooltip in only disabled state of the button, you can checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mihaifm/W7XNU/200/), The idea is to add the tooltip to a parent element with the selector option, and then add/remove the rel attribute when enabling/disabling the button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kamal... But You gave the solution for the disabled button. My scenario is the button should be enabled. If form.$valid condition fails then only the button go to disable. How to add that condition?

Comment: @YAZHINIK I have updated my answer to add your scenario with the help of a jsfiddle.

Comment: you are using two buttons. But in my scenario, there is only one button which is disabled while the form is invalid. After filling the mandatory field it will be changed to enable

Comment: @YAZHINIK you can change the condition of disable/enable in above fiddle. Still if the problem persists you can demo your code in a jsfiddle to make your situation understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"][disabled]').hover(function () {
  $(this).tooltip();
});
```

You'll need to ensure that your button has a CSS attribute of `disabled` set by default for this to work correctly (ie. set to `true` initially until the form details are valid in which case your code will need to change it to `false`).

Comment: You can use `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"][disabled]')` and remove `if`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @fen1x

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, I'm not sure if I understand what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('button').mouseenter(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){
     var title = $(this).prop('title');
      $(this).append('<div class="tooltip">'+ title +'</div>');
      $('.tooltip').show();
      $(this).prop('title','');
    }
  }).mouseleave(function(){
  $('.tooltip').hide();
  });     

});
```

```css
.tooltip{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-toggle="tooltip" title=" Please fill the mandatory fields..!" type="submit"
    class="submit disabled">Submit</button>
```